# Sending Email Notifications for Service Expiry in OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I want to be able to send service expiry email notifications to my customers.

**Scenario 1:**
Company XYZ has subscribed for Service A which expires in 6 months. I would like the customer to receive notifications 3 months/1 month/1week and on day of expiry.

**Scenario 2:**
Company ABC has subscribed for:

- Service A which expires in 1 year - Notifications to be sent are
  3months/1month/2weeks/1week and on day of expiry.
- Service B whichexpires in 3 months - Notifications to be sent are
  1month/2weeks/1week and on day of expiry.
- Service C which expires in 1 month - Notifications to be sent are 2weeks/1week and on day of expiry.

Based on the above scenarios for notifications.

1. Is there an existing plugin that would do the above for me?
2. If I were to build a plugin using **builder**, for adding customers, their emails and their services. How do I send notifications for expiry? Would this require **cronjobs**?

Comment: I think there is no a plugin that do that specifically but you can do it pretty easy with Laravel notifications and the Scheduler, I think you can create a console command for your plugin and programmatically read your clients table check for the expiring date and perform the notifications accordingly your business rules, maybe saving in a column or another table the notifications sent

Comment: Let me try this